# angular way of getting value of ng repeat inside directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'd like to have a liste, generated by a ng-repeat. 
Each list item contains a name and an input field that holds a number.

I'd like to change this number using a directive, but i've got no idea how i can address this value from inside the directive.

a working plunkr is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BXsTqqETkGkgvRxGyWi2?p=preview

and here is the directive so far:

```
app.directive('keyCommand', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  element.on("keydown", function(event){
    element.after("!");
    //on arrow right
    if (event.which==39){
      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!! HOW TO CHANGE THE CURRENT AMOUNT?
      item.amount++;
    } 
    });
  }
};      
});
```

I'm quite new to angular (obviously), and any hint in the right direction would be great. I've tried using required:"ngmodel", or passing something into the function but nothing worked.

Thanks a lots
Markus

Comment: Probably using ng-keyup and ng-value on the input element is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, Thats what i'm using at the moment, but i wanted to get my head around directives.

Comment: With angular you put as much of the handlers and application logic in the markup as you can. What you've got in your code above is more the jQuery way of doing things.

Comment: So controlling/ changing values would be done by calling functions from the markup and directives only for DOM Manipulation?

Comment: DOM manipulation is done through all the built-in angular directives - ng-if, ng-show, ng-repeat - and when you want to handle keyup on an input ng-keyup. The function that ng-keyup calls still lives in your controller/link function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
  scope.item.amount++;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/brRDm8eGttcr8yUPSEyY?p=preview

You can also use @inorganik suggestion: (if this is the behavior you want)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.amount" ng-keyup="item.amount=item.amount+1" />{{item.name}}
```

Comment: You'll need to define scope.item.amount first or it will throw an undefined error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint/solution:)
Scottie, where would this be defined? Isn't it already defined via the controller?